# Помогите с выборкой SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Есть таблица courses

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | firstCourse |
| 321 | secondCourse |

Есть таблица course, которая содержит в одном из столбцов xml структуру с данными курса. В том числе с id каталога, в котором этот курс находится(role_id) при этом course.id=courses.id:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | <course...> |
| 321 | <course...> |

Данный xml имеет следующую структуру, в которой главное для меня это список id каталогов, в которых может содержаться данный курс:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
    ...
    <role_id>0x5C0F8D957FC1671F</role_id>
    <role_id>0x6283A7F92D77546A</role_id>
    <role_id>0x62C84DCD14786E5B</role_id>
    ...
</course>
```

И наконец есть таблица roles, которая содержит в себе id каталогов и коды:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 546 | firstCatalog |
| 845 | secondCatalog |

Мне необходимо сделать запрос имея только код каталога, который бы мне сформировал бы следующую таблицу:

| role_id | role_code | course_id | course_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 546 | firstCatalog | 123 | firstCourse |
| 546 | firstCatalog | 321 | secondCourse |
| 546 | firstCatalog | id курса из таблицы courses | code курса из таблицы courses |

Другими словами мне необходимо по коду каталога найти все курсы, которые хранятся в этом каталоге через такую довольно сложную для меня цепочку джоинов и подзапросов. Буду рад примерам! Заранее спасибо!

```
  -- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @courses TABLE (id  bigint PRIMARY KEY, code VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @courses (id, code) VALUES
(6836290143006832700, 'motivation_ORG'),
(6882720723965317721, 'rise_career'),
(7099728121055442750, 'gift_cards');

    DECLARE @course TABLE (id bigint, [data] XML);
    INSERT @course (id, data) VALUES
    (6836290143006832700, N'<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
                                <role_id>7099728487018208760</role_id>
                                <role_id>7099724487018208760</role_id>
                            </course> '),
    (6882720723965317721, N'<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
                                <role_id>7024413919874268590</role_id>
                                <role_id>7099724487018208760</role_id>
                            </course> '),
    (7099728121055442750, N'<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
                                <role_id>7024413919874268590</role_id>
                                <role_id>7099724487018208760</role_id>
                            </course> ');
    
    DECLARE @roles TABLE (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, code VARCHAR(20));
    INSERT @roles (id, code) VALUES
    (7024413919874268590, 'wel'),
    (7099728487018208760, 'kass');
    -- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец
    
    SELECT * FROM @courses;
    SELECT * FROM @course;
    SELECT * FROM @roles;
```

Ожидаемый результат: запрос производится по одному из кодов категории ('wel' или 'kass') Запрос должен вывести `id, code` всех курсов из таблицы courses, относящиеся к категории с кодом 'wel'. Проблема в том, что эта связь существует только через таблицу course, в которой, в data в виде xml хранится перечень id каталогов, в которых пристутсвует курс.

Comment: `role_id` это `ID` каталога, или что? вы в примере упростили вид или что? формат данных несколько не похож. и укажите какая именно СУБД используется с версией

Comment: role_id - это id каталога, верно! Он хранится в таблице roles. Там же хранится и code каталога.
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4532098) - 11.0.7493.4 (X64)  Dec 24 2019 19:33:24  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Коллеги, очень нужна помощь!!!

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Добавил, если правильно вас понял

Comment: Очень близко. Пожалуйста, сделайте операторы INSERT с реальными данными.  T-SQL должен работать в SSMS. как есть.

Comment: Добавил. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как INSERT`ом вставляются данные xml

Comment: Посмотрите, как это сделать, в ответе. И используйте реальные данные, а не фиктивные.

Comment: Спасибо! Изменил вопрос свой

Comment: (1) готово. А как насчет (3)??? (3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.

Comment: Написал.  По поводу моих попыток - не буду добавлять,  т.к. они не работали совсем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137772/discussion-between-elarri-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Answer (score 0):

**T-SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @courses TABLE (id  INT PRIMARY KEY, code VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @courses (id, code) VALUES
(123, 'firstCourse'),
(321, 'secondCourse');

DECLARE @course TABLE (id INT, [data] XML);
INSERT @course (id, data) VALUES
(123, N'<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
            <role_id>0x5C0F8D957FC1671F</role_id>
            <role_id>0x6283A7F92D77546A</role_id>
            <role_id>0x62C84DCD14786E5B</role_id>
        </course> '),
(321, N'<course SPXML-FORM="x-local://wtv/wtv_course.xmd">
            <role_id>0x5C0F8D957FC1671F</role_id>
            <role_id>0x6283A7F92D77546A</role_id>
            <role_id>0x62C84DCD14786E5B</role_id>
        </course> ');

DECLARE @roles TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, code VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @roles (id, code) VALUES
(546, 'firstCatalog'),
(845, 'secondCatalog');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT * FROM @courses;
SELECT * FROM @course;
SELECT * FROM @roles;
```

Comment: Обновил по данному лекалу. В комментариях предыдущих написал, как пытаюсь достать нужные мне курсы. Не получается все равно

Comment: коллеги, есть мысли? Очень нужна помощь!

Comment: добрый день! К сожалению, нет такой возможности с рабочего места. На данный момент могу предложить только пообщаться в чате, который открыт в комментариях под самим вопросом

Comment: отправил приглашение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137779/discussion-between-elarri-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Comment: Таблица @roles не имеет отношения (relationships) к другим таблицам.

Comment: (3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных ???

Comment: Почему не имеет. Таблица roles связана с таблицей course через id

Comment: @roles.id = (7024413919874268590, 7099728487018208760) не существует в других таблицах.

Comment: У меня в моей программе изначально есть только код каталога (таблица roles), например 'wel'. Это соответствует id = 7024413919874268590 в таблице roles. Зная этот id, мне надо найти две записи из таблицы course, так как такой id есть в данных xml таблицы course (2 последние строки из трех). Зная это я могу найти строки в таблице courses: (6882720723965317721, 'rise_career'),
(7099728121055442750, 'gift_cards');

Comment: Когда вы находитесь в среде (дома?), где вы можете использовать Skype или MS Teams, свяжитесь со мной.